# Two aliases for same node in Drupal?

Tags: php, url, drupal, alias

I am working on a Drupal website. I need to automatically generate 2 url aliases for the same node on the website.
I have tried installing Pathauto but it lets me generate only 1 alias when a new page is created. Is it possible to have it automatically create 2 aliases when the page is created?

Do we do this via the module itself or can we have this done by code?

Comment: Did you see this thread? https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/2907491

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  This would be better answered on [drupal.se].  Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You closed my question on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com) instead of closing it here

Comment: You [post on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308174/how-to-automatically-generate-two-aliases-for-the-same-node) is indeed closed, but I'm not the one that closed it.  I'm not active on that site, I only have 103 rep there.   I voted to close the question here, but as of right now mine is the only close vote, and it would require three of them.  It was closed there because they requested additional details from you.  You should edit your question there to add those details and delete your question here.

Answer (score 1):

A single node can have as many aliases as you want and can be generated automatically, but not with pathauto.
Check https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/291584/3167 to learn how to "build" and store an alias and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/9.x to find the right hook.

You will have to build a little module, but it's quite easy: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules

And now think twice about it, many search engines will consider that you have "duplicated content" and they don't like it: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content

Answer (score -2):

In drupal, creating 2 URL aliases for one node is not possible. You can create only one URL alias for one node.

Comment: Not true. A node can have as many alias as you want. You can not do it using pathauto, but that is a very different thing.